# With $50$ options, what is the average random chooses until are a used

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random, coupon-collector

In the scenario where there are $50$ options and $1$ option is chosen randomly at a time, on how many times would it take until all options are chosen on an average attempt?

Then, if there are again $50$ options, and $1$ option is chosen at time, but with a random number that is influenced like:

$1$ would be chosen twice as often as $2$, $2$ would be chosen twice as often as $3$, $3$ would be chosen twice as often as $4$, etc. I think this would be $y = 2x$.

How many times would an option be chosen before all options would be chosen on an average attempt?

I am not for sure if this is possible, but it seems like it would be.

Comment: See [Probability question - how many cycles before all items are chosen](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/631053) or [Expected number of turns so that all balls get painted in blue color](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3188771) - also numerous similar questions.

Comment: And see [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem), which has the tag [tag:coupon-collector] on this site.

Comment: @joriki, Thanks. Didn't know that was what this type of problem was called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question is the standard [coupon collector’s problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). The answer is

$$
50H_{50}\approx224.96\;,
$$

where $H_{50}$ is the $50$-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

For the second question, with unequal probabilities, see the excellent collection of answers at [Coupon collector's problem: mean and variance in number of coupons to be collected to complete a set (unequal probabilities)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453965).

In your case, the probabilities are

\begin{eqnarray}
p_i
&=&
\frac{2^{-i}}{\sum_{i=1}^n2^{-i}}
\\
&=&
\frac{2^{-i}}{1-2^{-n}}\;,
\end{eqnarray}

where $n=50$ is the number of options. This makes for an interesting sum; the expected time to choose all options is

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{\emptyset\ne S\subseteq[n]}(-1)^{|S|+1}\frac1{\sum_{i\in S}p_i}
=(2^n-1)\sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1}\frac{(-1)^{b(k)+1}}k\;,
\end{eqnarray}

where $b(k)$ is the [bit count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) of $k$ and $[n]$ is the set of the first $n$ positive integers.

The sum has $2^{50}-1\approx10^{15}$ terms, so it’s hard to evaluate exactly, and I don’t immediately see a way to simplify it; but it appears to converge rapidly with $n\to\infty$. At $n=15$, which is as far as Wolfram|Alpha can [calculate the sum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20%28-1%29%5EDigitCount%28k%2C2%2C1%29%20%2F%20k%20for%20k%20%3D%201..2%5E15-1) in the standard computation time, the first $27$ digits seem to have converged; they are

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1}\frac{(-1)^{b(k)+1}}k\approx1.19628326432525643722229163\;.
$$

Thus, the expected time to choose all options is about $1.20\cdot2^{50}\approx1.35\cdot10^{15}$. As might have been expected, this is dominated by the expected time $2^{50}-1$ that it takes to choose the $50$-th option with its astronomically low probability of $\left(2^{50}-1\right)^{-1}$ of being chosen, and the sum is already quite well approximated by the expected time $\left(1+\frac12-\frac13\right)\left(2^{50}-1\right)=\frac76\left(2^{50}-1\right)\approx1.17\cdot2^{50}$ that it takes to choose the $49$-th and the $50$-th option.